# Synchronization between Two SQL Server Databases, Online and Offline

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

We have a local intranet based Project Management tool, we built it in asp.net .net 4.0 and sql server 2008. We cannot access this system online as it is lan based, neither we want its files to be appear online. But most of the cases we and other managers need to post project on it from home, but the issue is we dont wana use this system only on online server but also local intranet should be working, live ip is not prefered in any case because of electricity issues etc. We have an idea in our mind, that if we launch the same published site on online server (dedicated vps), and people use to work on offline system, but we can make some .exe utility which will upload our latest records from offline server to online server using the internet, does sql server provide any built in functionality for this, what is the best way to do this, either with our own custom logic with windows task scheduler or .Net provides any kind of facility for that. The reason of not using this system only as online is, our employees used to upload files in GBs, and the internet is only 4MBps, which will slow down the work, also we dont want internet dependency every time, also there is security issue.

Regards
Atif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Microsoft Sync Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753